# Dummit & Foote 13.2.18

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having a hard time trying to understand why $k(x)$ is an extension of $k(t)$?

> Let $k$ be a field and let $k(x)$ be the field of rational functions in x with coefficients from $k$. Let $t \in k(x)$ be the rational function $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ with relatively prime polynomials $P(x), Q(x) \in k[x]$, with $Q(x) \neq 0$. Then $k(x)$ is an extension of $k(t)$.

In my understanding,
$t \in k(x)$ has the form of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$, which is the quotient of a polynomial $P$ about $x$ with coefficients in $k$ over another nonzero polynomial $Q$ about $x$ with coefficients in $k$. I write
$$P(x) = p_n x^n + \dots + p_1 x + p_0, p_i \in K$$
$$Q(x) = q_m x^m + \dots + q_1 x + q_0, q_i \in K$$
$$t = \frac{p_n x^n + \dots + p_1 x + p_0}{q_m x^m + \dots + q_1 x + q_0}$$

Then "elements in" (thanks alex) $k(t)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $k$ about $t = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$:
\begin{align}
k(t) =& k_l t^l + \dots + k_1 t + k_0, k_i \in K\\
=& k_l \Bigg(\frac{p_n x^n + \dots + p_1 x + p_0}{q_m x^m + \dots + q_1 x + q_0}\Bigg)^l + \dots + k_1 \frac{p_n x^n + \dots + p_1 x + p_0}{q_m x^m + \dots + q_1 x + q_0} + k_0, k_i \in K\\
\end{align}

And
$$k(x) = k_r x^r + \dots + k_1 x + k_0, k_i \in K$$

But how to see that $k(x)$ is an extension of $k(t)$? Since $k(t) = \frac{k(x)}{1}$ for any $k(x)$, so what can be contained in $k(x)$ but not $k(t)$?

Comment: "Then $k(t)$ is a polynomial$\ldots$" At this point you are already misunderstanding something. $t$ itself is the polynomial in $x$, and $k(t)$ is a field, not a polynomial.

Comment: Thanks @alex.jordan. I realized it should be "elements in $k(t)$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k(t)$ is a field and from $t\in k(x)$ we see that $k(t)$ is a subfield of $k(x)$. In other words, $k(x)$ is an extension field of $k(t)$. The conditions do not exclude the case $P(x)=x$, $Q(x)=1$, in which $k(t)=k(x)$, i.e. $[k(x):k(t)]=1$.